# problems with build params for accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modeling, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I'm trying to add the user_id to a nested attribute that gets built by a parent controller but it doesn't seem to have the desired effect?

Ie. I have a model called Place.rb which `accepts_nested_attributes_for :reviews` and `has_many :reviews, :as => :reviewable, :dependent => :destroy`

The nested attribute works fine and I build it inside the Places controller like so...

## new action

```
@review = @place.reviews.build(:user_id => current_user.id)
```

## create action

```
params[:place].merge(:user_id => current_user.id)
params[:place][:reviews_attributes].merge!(:user_id => current_user.id)* bad
@place = Place.new(params[:place])
```

this is the original, for the place model to get a user_id, now i need the user_id for the nested reviews model as well.  It might seem odd that places and reviews both have user_ids, but people can add new reviews for the same place...

possibly like this but doesn't work:

```
@place = Place.new(params[:place].merge(:user_id => current_user.id, :reviews_attributes => { :user_id => current_user.id } ))
```

get the error: `undefined method` with_indifferent_access' for 3:Fixnum`

or

```
@place = Place.new(params[:place].merge(:user_id => current_user.id, :reviews_attributes => { "0" =>  { :user_id => current_user.id }}))
```

which adds the correct user_id but replaces the content of the review with NULL ;-(

I was previously adding the user thru the form, but would like to do it thru the controller so that it only adds the user_id on creation, as a particular review might get updated by someone else and i don't want the update changing the user_id from the original writer...

old way which works:

```
<%= e.label :content, "Review" %><br />
<%= e.text_area :content, :rows => 20, :class => 'jquery_ckeditor' %><br />
<%= e.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %> #want to remove this line
```

but thru the controller the build method with options has no effect? Any ideas?  Can I not do this thru the build?

The output in log:

```
    Parameters: {"commit"=>"Submit", "action"=>"create", "city_id"=>"prague",
 "controller"=>"places", "place"=>{"address"=>"fsdfsdf", "name"=>"sdfsdfsd",
 "reviews_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"content"=>"<p>\r\n\tsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf</p>\r
\n"}}, "website"=>"", "city_id"=>"1036", "place_type"=>"1"}}
```

Comment: I didn't understand it very well. You're adding the `user_id` in the controller but it's not working, is that right? How were you building the `review` in the controller before?

Comment: I've been building the review thru the places controller the whole time and it works fine except before I was adding the user_id for the review via the view... which i included and now i'm trying to do it directly in the build method.  Ie before it was just @place.reviews.build and now i tried to with @place.reviews.build(:user_id => current_user.id)
which seems to work from the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
params[:place][:user_id] = current_user.id
params[:place][:reviews_attributes].each do |key, review|
  review[:user_id] = current_user.id
end if params[:place][:reviews_attributes]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `params[:review]` as the attributes' hash, you need to do a `merge!`:

```
params[:review].merge!(:user_id => current_user.id)
@review = @place.reviews.build(params[:review])
```

**Edit:** 
I'm also assuming you'll use this is on `create` method.

**Edit #2:**
It's not gonna work on `new` method because, as you can find at [railsapi.com](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.5/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M000966), the build method

> "only works if an associated object
>   already exists, not if it’s nil!"

**Edit #3:**
I'm not sure if this is the best way, but I tested here and It worked...

You have this parameters:

```
{"commit"=>"Submit", "action"=>"create", "city_id"=>"prague",
   "controller"=>"places", "place"=>{"address"=>"fsdfsdf", "name"=>"sdfsdfsd",
   "reviews_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"content"=>"<p>\r\n\tsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf 
   sdfsdfsdf</p>\r\n"}}, "website"=>"", "city_id"=>"1036", "place_type"=>"1"}}
```

So you can access reviews' attributes this way: `params[:place][:reviews_attributes]` and, to merge the `user_id` attribute, you can do:

```
params[:place][:reviews_attributes].each_value {
   |v| v.merge!(:user_id => current_user.id) 
}
```

Now `params[:place][:reviews_attributes]` looks like this example:

```
{"0"=>{
   "user_id"=>"1",
   "content"=>"<p>\r\n\tsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf</p>\r\n"
}}
```

Comment: That's too ugly so i added the above to the question with specific new and create actions.

Comment: i'm happy to do it on create, but i'm not sure how to merge the nested attribute... see above.  :reviews_attributes => { :user_id => current_user.id } doesn't work.

Comment: it's `params[:reviews_attributes].merge!(:user_id => current_user.id)`

Comment: with that i get "undefined method `merge!' for nil:NilClass", tried params[:place][:reviews_attributes].merge!(:user_id => current_user.id), gets indifferent access error. added my log above.

Answer (score 1):

You may or may not want to add a hidden field in the form that includes the user_id. Then the params hash will already have the value. If you're worried about tampering, you could compare it to the current_user.id. Then again, maybe that's why you're trying it this way to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using form_for with a poor syntax. I have quit using hidden_fields after looking at this: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for

and this comment: (God Bless You, nachocab!)

> nachocab -  November 2, 2008 params
>   hash gets the model id automatically
>
> The params hash gets automatically
>   populated with the id of every model
>   that gets passed to form_for. If we
>   were creating a song inside an
>   existing album:
>
> URL:/albums/209/songs/new   form_for
>   [@album, @song] do |f|
>       ...
>       f.submit "Add"   end
>
> The params hash would be:
>
> params = {"commit"=>"Add",
>               "authenticity_token"=>"...",
>               "album_id"=>"209",
>               "song"=>{"song_attributes"=>{...}}
>               }
>
> So, in the songs_controller you could
>   use this album_id in a before_filter:
>
> before_filter :find_album
>   protected   def find_album
>       @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])   end
>
> If you only did this:
>
> form_for @song do |f|
>
> You would get this params hash:
>
> params = {"commit"=>"Add",
>               "authenticity_token"=>"...",
>               "song"=>{"song_attributes"=>{...}}
>               }